# Scraping an email with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some informations from a website, but I am unable to exctract the email.
I'm new to python (and coding), I'm sorry for this low-level question.

This code works for everything but the email:

```
import requests, bs4
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.parrocchiemap.it/parrocchiemap/consultazione/parrocchie/scheda.jsp?icsc=2170056")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("content")

print(elem.text)
```

I tried

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("mail")
```

but it prints empty

Comment: Can you show the relevant part(s) of the page source?

Comment: @AMC is [this](https://i.imgur.com/BKb4nRk.png) what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Have you tried sleeping/waiting before searching for the element?

Comment: Try it `elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mail > a").get_attribute("onclick")`.

Comment: @AMC It didn't work sadly.

Comment: @Frenesy I tried it on my computer using `time.sleep(5)` and it worked.